# How to make calls and gets events from php or nodejs with TAPI 2.0/2.1 under unix system?

Tags: php, node.js, unix, tapi

I need to connect to a pbx with TAPI 2.0/2.1 protocol, how can i make calls and gets pbx events under unix system with php or nodejs?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge and memory, TAPI is an interface, not a protocol. Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephony_Application_Programming_Interface), the 2.0 is written in C and “can be awkward to use from many other programming languages”, so if you can use the 3.0 over COM, that might be an option.

Comment: That said, TAPI is a Microsoft thing, and is probably pretty hard to implement on non-MS systems. Although many PBXs might support TAPI, that’s intended for Windows support specifically. Is the PBX directly attached to this machine with something like a serial interface, or is it networked?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Right now i have no code, i need to came up with a solution of how to interact with a tapi interface with php or nodejs under unix system but i have no idea. I see some solutions under windows loading the COM("TAPI.TAPI.1") but i don't know under unix how to do it

Comment: COM is Windows-only to the best of my knowledge. There’s ways to tap COM in .Net, but I’m also pretty certain that’s a Windows-only feature. As noted previously, TAPI is Windows, too. I’m fairly confident in saying that short of running a VM, TAPI + Unix isn’t an option. Maybe [Asterisk](https://www.asterisk.org/downloads/) will do what you want?

Comment: Sure, i'm already interfaced with asterisk unfortunately i have a fucking alcatel to interface with ;) thanks all guys